# Blank rows in UITableView after coverting code for swift 2.0 and xcode 7

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, swift2, xcode7

I am getting blank rows on top of my UITableView also on selecting the row the index is not coming correct. It was working fine before but its not working after i did changes for xcode 7 and swift 2.0. Below is my code. Let me know if you have any suggestions to fix this issue.

```
class DistributionAPNTableViewController: UITableViewController, UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate,UpdateUIDelegate {

    var jsonReleaseNotificationArray:NSArray = []


    var activityView : UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        let url: String = Constants.RelNotificationsURL
        let restCall = CallRESTParser()
        restCall.uiDelegate=self
        self.showProgress()
        restCall.processRequest(url,type: Constants.RelNotificationsType)
    }


    func UpdateReleaseNotificationUI(jsonArray:NSArray){
        self.dismissProgress()
        jsonReleaseNotificationArray = jsonArray
        self.tableView.reloadData()


    }

    override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        var cnt:Int = 0
        if jsonReleaseNotificationArray.count > 0 {
            cnt = jsonReleaseNotificationArray.count
        }
        else if jsonReleaseNotificationArray.count == 0{
            cnt =  1
        }
        return cnt
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cellIdentifier = "RelCell"

        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
                reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
        if jsonReleaseNotificationArray.count > 0{

            let jsonResult = jsonReleaseNotificationArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
        if let noti = jsonResult!.objectForKey("notification") as? String{
            cell.textLabel?.text = noti
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:14)
        }
        if let user = jsonResult!.objectForKey("userid") as? String{
            cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "Updated By : \(user)"
        }
        }else
        {
            cell.textLabel?.text = "There is no release notifications yet."
            cell.textLabel?.font = UIFont(name:"Avenir", size:14)

        }
        return cell
    }
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

        let jsonResult = jsonReleaseNotificationArray[indexPath.row] as? NSDictionary
        let destination:NotificationDetails = storyboard!.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("notification") as! NotificationDetails
        if let noti = jsonResult!.objectForKey("notification") as? String{
            destination.messageStr = noti
        }
        if let user = jsonResult!.objectForKey("userid") as? String{
            destination.updatedByStr = user
        }


        navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    }

    func UpdateProjectUI(data:NSDictionary){
    }
    @available(iOS 8.0, *)
    func adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController(controller: UIPresentationController) -> UIModalPresentationStyle
    {
        return UIModalPresentationStyle.None
    }

    func showProgress() {

        self.view.alpha = 0.5

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = false

        self.activityView.center = self.view.center
        self.activityView.color = UIColor.blackColor()

        self.view .addSubview( self.activityView )

        self.activityView.startAnimating()
    }


    func dismissProgress () {

        self.activityView.stopAnimating()

        self.activityView.removeFromSuperview()

        self.view.alpha = 1.0

        self.view.userInteractionEnabled = true
    }
    func UpdateRelNotiByMsgUI(data:NSDictionary){
    }
    func ErrorHasOccured(error:String){
        self.dismissProgress()
        if #available(iOS 8.0, *) {
            let alert = UIAlertController(title: "IBM Vidur", message: error, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else {
            let alertController: UIAlertView = UIAlertView(title: "IBM Vidur", message:error, delegate: nil, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
            alertController.show()
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier, forIndexPath: indexPath)

cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle,
                reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
```

These two lines could make some confusion. You are dequeueing a cell, than you just initiate an other one.

I think, you should only be using the first line to create tableView cells. And the cell should be set up properly in the tableView as a prototype cell.

Comment: Ok so how do we set it in single line? I need the subtitles as well.

Comment: Design your tableViewCell in the storyboard, to have the desired labels you need.

Answer (score 1):

> blank rows on top of my UITableView also on selecting the row the
>   index is not coming correct

This clearly indicates that in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function, for some of the cells, `textLabel` & `detailTextLabel` is not being set at all in which case cell would appear empty. You may verify this by tapping on the first cell and print the cell index in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function.

I would advise you to put a break point in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` function and check for each empty row indexes the value being set on cell.